# React-Redux useSelector typescript type for state

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm using the `useSelector(state => state.SLICE_NAME)` hook from React-Redux however I'm having difficulty defining the `state` parameter. It is set by default as `unknown` so I get an error when I try to return `state.SLICE_NAME` (`Error: Object is of type 'unknown'`).

How do I define the `state` type without having to manually create a separate state type and adding in every new state definition as they're created?

I've tried defining state as `typeof store` however that doesn't work.

Some code to help explain:

```
// navDrawer.ts

import { createSlice } from "redux-starter-kit";

// navDrawer initial state
export interface NavDrawerInitialState {
  open: boolean;
}

const navDrawerInitialState: NavDrawerInitialState = {
  open: false
};

// Create state slice
const { actions, reducer } = createSlice({
  slice: "navDrawer",
  initialState: navDrawerInitialState,
  reducers: {
    open: (state: NavDrawerInitialState) => {
      state.open = true;
    },
    close: (state: NavDrawerInitialState) => {
      state.open = false;
    }
  }
});

export const navDrawerActions = actions;
export default reducer;
```

```
// reducers.ts

import navDrawer from "./navDrawer";

const reducers = {
  navDrawer
};

export default reducers;
```

```
// store.ts

import { configureStore } from "redux-starter-kit";
import reducer from "./reducers";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer
});

export default store;
```

```
// Page.tsx

import React, { FC } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

const StateProvider: FC = () => {
  return <Provider store={store}><ChildComponent /></Provider>;
};

export default StateProvider;
```

```
// ChildComponent.tsx

import React, { FC } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const ChildComponent: FC = () => {
  const navDrawerState = useSelector(state => state.navDrawer); // ERROR OCCURS HERE. "state" is defined as 'unknown' so "state.navDrawer" throws an error.
  return <div>Text</div>
}
```

**Edit**: I noticed that the type definition for `configureStore()` contains the state as the first generic type. See screenshot below. If I can get the first generic value from `EnhancedStore` then I'll be able to use that to define state. Is there any way I can do this in Typescript?

[image]

Comment: A lot has changed since this question was asked. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65049635/3233055 is the "most" correct answer currently. @Jake you should select an answer.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

This might not be the answer but I use it like so:

```
const isLoggedIn = useSelector<IRootState, boolean>(state => state.user.loggedIn);
```

EDIT: Or use [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472105/react-redux-useselector-typescript-type-for-state/60885506#60885506) which is shorter/cleaner

```
const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.user.loggedIn);
```

---

**FYI:** To get the `IRootState`, there are a couple of options (from the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript)):

From `combineReducers()`:

```js
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
const rootReducer = combineReducers({})
export type IRootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

From `configureStore()`:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
const store = configureStore({ ... })
export type IRootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

Comment: This is the proper answer. People, stop upvoting the answer above and upvote this one.

Comment: Yup. Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: couldn't help laugh at statement above. great answer it helped as well

Comment: what is IRootState?

Comment: Use @peter-v-mørch answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60885506/2902063

Comment: @TuanDo, IRootState is the interface of your app's state, in my case it's the following:

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  foo: fooReducer,
})
export type IRootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think it's the correct answer, the best one would be to create createSelectorHook<YourStateType>.

Comment: I will also mention that it requires @types/react-redux to be installed (as of today)

Comment: LIFE SAVER! I love you @alextrastero

Answer (score 59):

You can create your custom typed useSelector like so:

```
import {
  useSelector as useReduxSelector,
  TypedUseSelectorHook,
} from 'react-redux'
import { RootState } from 'app/redux/store'

export const useSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useReduxSelector
```

where `RootState` is the type of the store, usually defined as:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

This is the method described in the [definitely typed declaration](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2ab7a8073719008b169a3069977cc66f2e87a1e2/types/react-redux/index.d.ts#L544).

Don't forget to install `@types/react-redux`.

Comment: `Type '{ navDrawer: Reducer<NavDrawerInitialState, AnyAction>; }' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.`
  `Type '{ navDrawer: Reducer<NavDrawerInitialState, AnyAction>; }' provides no match for the signature '(...args: any): any'.`

Comment: where happen that error, what's the code involved? doesn't seems related to the `TypedUseSelectorHook`

Comment: `const state = useSelector(
    (getState: ReturnType<typeof reducer>) => getState.navDrawer
  );`

Comment: Also, `export const useSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<ReturnType<typeof reducer>> = useReduxSelector` has the same error

Comment: where `reducer` come from in your example?

Comment: I edited my post. It's listed above under `reducers.ts`

Comment: Is this not even simpler ? `const { cars } = useSelector((s: RootState) => s.carReducer)`

Comment: TypedUseSelectorHook is deprecated, you should use something like `export const useSelector = createSelectorHook<VRampState>();`

Comment: @santamanno, thanks for let me know, I appended a note to redirect anyone to NearHuscarl's answer

Comment: actually, `TypedUseSelectorHook`'s deprecation was a rogue commit that has never been talked through with the react-redux team. It has since been undone. Please continue using `TypedUseSelectorHook` instead of `createSelectorHook`.

Comment: @phry thanks for correcting me. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: thanks @NearHuscarl, but I don't think you should delete the answer with createSelectorHook (as it's still a valid solution)

Answer (score 42):

Here is the suggestion (more or less) from [the redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/7.1/using-react-redux/static-typing#typing-the-useselector-hook):

```
import { RootState } from 'app/redux/store';
const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state: RootState => state.user.loggedIn);
```

The advantage over @Federkun's answer is that it is much simpler. The advantage over @alextrastero's answer is that I don't have to specify isLoggedIn's type manually.

---

**FYI:** To get the `RootState`, there are a couple of options (from the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript)):

From `combineReducers()`:

```js
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
const rootReducer = combineReducers({})
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

From `configureStore()`:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
const store = configureStore({ ... })
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

Comment: Simple and practical! Thanks!

Comment: Work extremely well. Thanks

Comment: I will also mention that it requires @types/react-redux to be installed (as of today)

Answer (score 36):

As per [Redux docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/nextjs#creating-a-redux-store-per-request), export the state as **RootState** in **store.tsx** file

```
// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

Then in component use it as

```
const navDrawerOpen = useSelector((state:RootState) => state.navDrawer.open);
```

Comment: This is the (complete) answer. Amazing how many of the answers here are not actually answers!

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. Cleanest and most correct answer I could find on the internet. Wish I could upvote more than once. Cheers!

Comment: This is the only answer that has both steps and files that need to be augmented in order to make this solution work. thank you @Pavan Jadda for this great answer.

Answer (score 14):

1. Create `config.d.ts`
2. Define your custom state

   ```
   import 'react-redux';
   import { ApplicationState } from '@store/index';
   declare module 'react-redux' {
     interface DefaultRootState extends ApplicationState {}
   }
   ```

Comment: That should be the actual selected answer.

Comment: This solution works like a charm but there is one small issue that the code completion of `ApplicationState` does not bring into `DefaultRootState`, how do you solve that?

Answer (score 6):

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zySeP5vH9c&ab_channel=LearnWithJason) video, Mark Erikson shows how to create some custom useAppSelector and useAppDispatch, to give them the correct types.
Example in hooks.ts:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store';

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

And then in store.ts we have:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import productsReducer from '../slices/products.slice';

const store = createStore(
  productsReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch; // Here we export the store's dispatch type
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>; // Here we export the store's state
```

I think it's the best and simpler approach nowadays.
Hope it's useful to somebody.

Comment: Thanks it's in 38:06 here is a link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zySeP5vH9c#t=38m6s

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [@Иван Яковлев](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10039155/%d0%98%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%af%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2), I've finally achieved my perfect solution :D

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from '../configureStore'

export const { store } = configureStore()
// We can use RootState type in every file in project
declare global {
  type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
}

// Thanks to that you will have ability to use useSelector hook with state value
declare module 'react-redux' {
  interface DefaultRootState extends RootState { }
}

const profile = useSelector(state => state.profile) // Profile is correctly typed
```

Answer (score 3):

Use typesafe-actions. It really makes life easy for you.

1. `npm install --save typesafe-actions`
2. Go to your reducer or rootReducer file and
3. `import { StateType } from 'typesafe-actions';`
4. Write your reducer function and
5. `export type Store = StateType<typeof yourReducer>;`

Then

6. Go to the ts file you want to use and
7. `import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';`
8. `import {Store} from 'your-reducer-or-wherever-file'`
9. Inside your component:
10. `const store = useSelector((store: Store) => { return {students: store.manager.students} });`

Notice how I used the Store type I exported from my reducer in the useSelector hook (the type of your store is what useSelector needs and you can get it easily with typesafe-actions as we just did).
Also, notice how I returned an object that contains all the states I want to use. You can get creative at this point, it doesn't matter. So, the store variable in line 10 has all the states and you could as well just destructure if you want.
You can read more on typesafe-actions from https://www.npmjs.com/package/typesafe-actions

Comment: I've tried the other listed solutions, maybe some are outdated but this is the only that worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 3):

there is a type that 'react-redux' bundle provide

```
import { RootStateOrAny} from "react-redux";

const recentActivityResponse = useSelector(
    (state: RootStateOrAny) => state.dashboard.recentActivityResponse
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

type RootState = {
    auth: {
        login: string
        isAuth: boolean
    }
}

const State: RootState = {
  auth: {
     login: ''
     isAuth: false
  }
}

export function useSelectorTyped<T>(fn: (state: RootState) => T): T {
  return useSelector(fn)
}

const LoginForm = () => {
    const { login, loginError } = useSelectorTyped(state => state.auth)
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
export interface IUser {
  userName: string;
}    

export interface IRootState {
  user: IUser;
} 

const user = useSelector<IRootState, IUser>(state => state.user);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to understand this thoroughly is the Redux docs themselves.

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript

They state

*Define Typed Hooks​
While it's possible to import the RootState and AppDispatch types into each component, it's better to create pre-typed versions of the useDispatch and useSelector hooks for usage in your application. This is important for a couple reasons:
For useSelector, it saves you the need to type (state: RootState) every time
For useDispatch, the default Dispatch type does not know about thunks or other middleware. In order to correctly dispatch thunks, you need to use the specific customized AppDispatch type from the store that includes the thunk middleware types, and use that with useDispatch. Adding a pre-typed useDispatch hook keeps you from forgetting to import AppDispatch where it's needed.*

Therefore the below should do the trick and always be used to avoid having to constantly type selectors or dispatches.

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found in code this snippet

```
/**
 * This interface can be augmented by users to add default types for the root state when
 * using `react-redux`.
 * Use module augmentation to append your own type definition in a your_custom_type.d.ts file.
 * https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation
 */
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
export interface DefaultRootState {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make an interface at store.ts that contans all the types of all state values of all files, and then import it and use it as the type of state whenever you use useState()

at foo.ts

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
const foo = createSlice({
    initialState: {value: "some value"}
})
export default foo.reducer
```

at store.ts

```
    import {foo} from "./foo.ts"
    import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
    interface RootState {
      foo: {
        value: string
      }
    }
    
    export default configureStore({
        reducer: {foo: foo}
    })
```

at distination file

```
import { RootState } from "../store"
import { useState } from "react-redux"
const bar = useState((state: RootState) => state.foo.value)
```

Answer (score -3):

You could just use any for the type.
Just another solution.