# EmptyObject on useSelector and RootState Type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, typescript-generics

I am using `combineReducers` from redux to combine multiple reducers into a root state of type
`RootStateType` currently I have only 1 reducer called `CounterReducer` with returning state type of `CounterStateType`.

**Problem** - The `RootStateType` is also getting unioned with type `EmptyObject` from typescript as I hover over it in vscode (shown in the image below).

[Types of RootStateType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1aiT.png)

I followed [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60885506/14646056) from the question [React-Redux useSelector typescript type for state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57472105/14646056) to use the useSelector hook from 'react-redux'.and the now the my useSelector hook is also getting the `EmptyObject` inferred from the types of `RootStateType` like this [Types of useSelector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLvB2.png)

**My question is** will this hamper the type safety of my code? as useSelector hook can also be passed an `EmptyObject`. or is there is any better way of using useSelector to get rid of that `EmptyObject` type from it?

**without using** @reduxjs/toolkit?

**Code**

**store.ts**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";

export type CounterStateType = {
  value: number;
};

type CounterActionType = {
  type: string;
};

const CounterInitialState = {
  value: 0,
};

const CounterReducer = (
  state: CounterStateType = CounterInitialState,
  action: CounterActionType
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREASE":
      return {
        value: state.value + 1,
      };
    case "DECREASE":
      return {
        value: state.value - 1,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  counter: CounterReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export type RootStateType = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatchType = typeof store.dispatch;

export default store;
```

**CounterComp.tsx**

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { RootStateType } from "../store/store";

import CounterButtons from "./CounterButtons";

const CounterComp = () => {
  const counter = useSelector((state: RootStateType) => {
    return state.counter.value;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
      <CounterButtons />
    </>
  );
};

export default CounterComp;
```

**alternatively**, if I would have been working with a single reducer then for example my `store` would have been something like

```
export type CounterStateType = {
  value: number;
};

const store = createStore(CounterReducer);
```

and useSelector hook would have been like

```
const counter = useSelector<CounterStateType, CounterStateType["value"]>(
    (state) => {
      return state.value;
    }
  );
```

which would have ensured [100% type safety](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofui3.png).

How do I do the same with multiple reducers?

Comment: I am also interested in this. Following Redux docs for typing `RootState` yields results that "work" technically, but with combineReducers, autocomplete is not working for `state.myReducerKey` (for example). Even though if I do this right next to where I define the `RootState` type --> `let x: RootState['myReducerKey']` (this autocompletes fine).  However, in the context of `useSelector<RootState>` or `useAppSelector` suggested in the docs, this key cannot be inferred on `state` -- why?

Comment: Got any luck with this?