# using IRootState type in useSelector

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, react-typescript

I use IRootState type for useSelector in redux-toolkit (typeScript) like this :

```
    const usersPage = useSelector<IRootState, number>((state) => state.users.page)
```

I saw this code in this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472105/react-redux-useselector-typescript-type-for-state)  in stackoverflow !

But now my question is from where I can import this type !?
or more ! I have to make this or import this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define that type yourself, see here in the docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-state-type