# I have a problem with a type unknown in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

It's my first time using typescript and I'm getting a problem with the variable called "state" as it's use to get my list of users form the api but I get this error "'state' is of type 'unknown'" even though it actually works. As I said it's my first time with typescript and I dontu fully understand why it works if it has an error.

```
//React Imports
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
//MUI Imports
import Navbar from "../../Components/Navbar";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import { CardMedia } from "@mui/material";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
//Redux Imports
import { fetchAllUsers } from "../../redux/slices/users";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

function Users() {
  const { list: users } = useSelector((state) => state.users);//Error in state.users

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchAllUsers() as any);
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="Users">
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <br></br>
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
          {users.map((user, index) => (
            <Grid item xs={3.1}>
              <Card>
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  image={user.avatar}
                  alt="avatar image"
                ></CardMedia>
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5">
                    {user.first_name} {user.last_name}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6">
                    {user.email}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Users;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Redux useSelector typescript type for state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472105/react-redux-useselector-typescript-type-for-state)

Answer (score 1):

```
  const { list: users } = useSelector((state:SPECIFYTYPEHERE) => state.users);//Error in state.users
```

You need to specify the type of state after the colon in typescript otherwise the state will be inferred as unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either include type definition for state in here (which you've probably written in the reducer part) or you can use conditional chaining `state!.users` or `state!.users` or you can give any as the type to state `(state:any)`